# Pass in a parameter to model in codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently in my model I am hardcoding in 'XYZ'. This works cause I get the correct number of XYZ buildings but there 50 other buildings that also need. It doesn't make sense for me to hardcode all buildings.

How do I pass this the building as a parameter.

My view file looks like this:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel tile">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2>Buildings</h2>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
      <h4>Total work requests</h4>
      <?php foreach ($buildings as $bldg){?>
        <div class="widget_summary">
          <div class="w_left w_25">
            <span><?php echo $bldg['Building_Code'];?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="w_center w_55">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 66%;">
                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w_right w_20">
            <span><?php echo $countBuildings; ?>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```html
$data["countBuildings"]= $this->Buildings_model->getBldgCount('XYZ');
$this->load->view('main/header');
$this->load->view('main/body', $data);
$this->load->view('main/footer');
```

My model looks like this:

```html
public function getBldgCount($queryBuilding){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('Building_Code', $queryBuilding);
  $this->db->from('work_requests');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

the best approach is to use custom helper because you need to count all 50 type of buildings

Create helper with name `custom_helper.php` and place it `helpers` folder and autoload with `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');
```

`custom_helper.php` should be like this :

```
function count_building_by_code($building_code)
{
    $ci = & get_instance();
    /* Omit this line if you autoload model in autoload.php*/
    $ci->load->model('Buildings_model');
    $count = $ci->Buildings_model->getBldgCount($building_code);
    return $count;
}
```

The model code :

```
public function getBldgCount($building_code)
    {
        if ($building_code)
        {
            $this->db->where('Building_Code',$building_code);
            return $this->db->count_all_results('work_requests');
        }
    }
```

The View :

```
<?php foreach ($buildings as $bldg){?>
        <div class="widget_summary">
          <div class="w_left w_25">
            <span><?php echo $bldg['Building_Code'];?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="w_center w_55">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 66%;">
                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w_right w_20">
            <span><?php echo count_building_by_code($bldg['Building_Code']); ?>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: if my answer helps you don't hesitate to mark it as green

Comment: This did the trick! I never thought about adding in a helper function.

Comment: If I wanted to get a percentage value instead of count how would I go about doing that?

Comment: then u have to query according to the requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the approach.
There is no need to have the building code hard coded. You even don't need to pass the building code.

You need to use group by in your query such that it returns all the building with count. Your model function will be something like below:

```
public function getBldgCount(){
    $this->db->select('Building_Code, COUNT(id) as total');
    $this->db->group_by('Building_Code');
    $this->db->get('work_requests');
}
```

Comment: could you please delete one of your practically identical answers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the approach.
There is no need to have the building code hard coded. You don't even need to pass the building code.

You need to use group by in your query such that it returns all the building with count.

```
public function getBldgCount(){
    $this->db->select('Building_Code, COUNT(id) as total');
    $this->db->group_by('Building_Code');
    $this->db->get('work_requests');
}
```

Comment: could you please delete one of your practically identical answers?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you have to set the array value in `$data` of buildings counts.

In controller **replace:**

```
$data["countBuildings"]= $this->Buildings_model->getBldgCount('XYZ');
$this->load->view('main/header');
$this->load->view('main/body', $data);
$this->load->view('main/footer');
```

**With:**

```
foreach($data['buildings'] as $k=>$v){
    $data["buildingcount"][$k]["count"] = $this->Buildings_model->getBldgCount($v);
}

$this->load->view('main/header');
$this->load->view('main/body', $data);
$this->load->view('main/footer');
```

You have to update as needed the view code to accommodate the new buildings counts data.

**Updated View:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel tile">
    <div class="x_title">
      <h2>Buildings</h2>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
      <h4>Total work requests</h4>
      <?php foreach ($buildings as $bk=>$bldg){?>
        <div class="widget_summary">
          <div class="w_left w_25">
            <span><?php echo $bldg['Building_Code'];?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="w_center w_55">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 66%;">
                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w_right w_20">
            <span><?php echo $buildingcount[$bk]['count']; ?>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to update my model? Right now im getting the following database error:

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `work_requests` WHERE `Building_Code` = Array

Filename: models/Buildings_model.php